# How to add 24 hours in date variable in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I've a date variable `EndDate` stored in localStorage. Now I want to add exact 24 hours in that. Localstorage value is Sun Jun 09 2019 20:39:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

```
    var endDate = new Date();
    endDate.setDate(new Date(localStorage.getItem("requestDate")).getDate() + 1);
```

If I run this code it is returning Mon Jun 10 2019 07:58:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time). Which is wrong because time is current datetime time.

```
    var endDate = new Date();
    endDate.setDate(new Date(localStorage.getItem("requestDate")).getDate() + 1);
    // Do your operations
    endDate.setTime(new Date(localStorage.getItem("requestDate")).getTime() + 24);
```

If I run above code it is returning Sun Jun 09 2019 20:39:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), setTime overrides previous date value.

**Desired Output is Mon Jun 10 2019 20:39:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

Comment: Just to check, is `requestDate` in unix time, or ISO string..? Or is it literally the string value of 'Sun Jun 09 2019 20:39:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'

Comment: requestDate is string because it is stored in localStorage.

Comment: GetExisting hours and set 24 hours to the date. `newDate.setHours(newDate.getHours() + 24)` Where `newDate` is `newDate = new Date(stringDate)`

Comment: Yup, I understand. So what you are trying to do, is to get the date value of `requestDate`, add 24 hours to it, and assign the reference to the variable, `endDate`?

Comment: @wentjun - yes exactly. Although xyz answer is working for me :)

Comment: Yup, I was about to mention that too! :) it is actually not as complicated as it seems

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope  this will work

```
var endDate = new Date(localStorage.getItem("requestDate"));
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new Date object, you can create a date object from your localStorage and increment on that. To clarify my point check the code below:

```
var startDate = new Date(localStorage.getItem("requestDate"))
var endDate = new Date(startDate)
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 1)
console.log('start date', startDate.toString())
console.log('end date', end date.toString())
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add as days to specific date, can use following code.

```
var startDate = new Date(localStorage.getItem("requestDate"));
var endDate = new Date(startDate);
endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);

console.log("Start date: " + startDate);
console.log("End date: " + endDate);
```

If you need add as hours to specific date, an use following code.

```
var hours = 10;
var startTime = new Date(localStorage.getItem("requestDate"));
var endTime = new Date(startTime.getTime() + (hours*60*60*1000));
console.log("Start time: " + startTime);
console.log("End time: " + endTime);
```